# How to make a binary tree with unique indexes in F#

Tags: f#, binary-tree

How do you write a recursive function to build a binary tree where leafs are (value,index) with index a unique successive integer?

Current code is something like:

```
let rec MakeTree size = 
    if size = 0 then 0 else
      match ran.Next (3) with
       | 0 -> Cow (MakeTree (size-1),MakeTree (size-1))
       | 1 -> Dog (MakeTree (size-1),MakeTree (size-1))
       | 2 -> Cat (MakeTree (size-1),MakeTree (size-1))
```

Comment: I think you must to provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a version without values, but they are easy to add:

Define the tree like:

```
type Tree<'T when 'T: comparison> = 
| Empty 
| Node of 'T * Tree<'T> * Tree<'T>
```

And make a insert function like

```
let rec insert index = function
| Empty -> Node(index, Empty, Empty)
| Node(i, left, right) when index < i -> Node(i, insert index left, right)
| Node(i, left, right) when index > i -> Node(i, left, insert index right)
| Node(i, left, right) when index = i -> Node(index, left, right)
| Node(_, _, _) as n -> n
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for an insert function - rather a way to create the tree with successive integers at the leafs.

Comment: So you want to create a tree like http://i.imgur.com/pmbhpPp.png from a  list like [(6,5);(6,2);(7,4);(3,3);(4,3);(3,2);(3,5);(5,3)] ?

Comment: No - the tree will be built recursively with a random number generator.

Comment: Then I am not what you want the tree to look like. Can you poat a small example tree and/or the code your have now.